# Inserting Drupal nodes to MongoDB on creation/modification

Tags: php, mongodb, drupal

I am attempting to create a JSON API using Node.js and MongoDB for a Drupal 7 based CMS. I would like the data being sent to the MySQL database to be copied to the MongoDB database as soon as there is an insert of update event.

I have tried the [MongoDB module for Drupal](https://drupal.org/project/mongodb). However, it does not insert/update the body of the article to MongoDB. I have checked [Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush) as well. However, the Drush method does not insert/update to MongoDB on the fly.

What is the best method to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to add your logic in node_update hook. So, on every node updation you can push the changes to Mongodb.

```
function MYMODULE_node_update($node) {
  // code to push the changes to Mongodb.
}
```

You can also implement similar logic in insert & delete hooks.